# How to filter out json object from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have this JSON response **I want to filter out the product that contains specific id inside the categories arrays**

```
[
 {
    "id": 7721,
    "name": "Grilled kebab corn tomato special",
    "purchase_note": "",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 50,
            "name": "All recipes",
            "slug": "0-all-recipes"
        },
        {
            "id": 94,
            "name": "Chef's Special",
            "slug": "chefs-special"
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    "id": 7722,
    "name": "Grilled kebab corn tomato special",
    "purchase_note": "",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 112,
            "name": "All recipes",
            "slug": "0-all-recipes"
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Chef's Special",
            "slug": "chefs-special"
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

Here's an example **I want to filter out the object that contains id 112 in the categories array**
let's say I want this result from the JSON object given above

```
[
 {
    "id": 7722,
    "name": "Grilled kebab corn tomato special",
    "purchase_note": "",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 112,
            "name": "All recipes",
            "slug": "0-all-recipes"
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Chef's Special",
            "slug": "chefs-special"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

**In JavaScript**

Thanks (:

That's what I have tried and it's working to filter out depends on the string inside the objects but I couldn't find a way to filter out depends on the categories id

here's my try

```
  menuData = the json response 

 menuData.filter(menuData => menuData.name == "Grilled kebab corn tomato special");
```

also, I've tried to use this

```
 menuData = the json response 

 menuData.filter(menuData => menuData.categories.map((o) => o.id) == 112);
```

Comment: If you have tried to filter it please show what you've tried and we can help you get past problems

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
const filtered = items.filter(item =>
  item.categories.filter(c => c.id == 112).length > 0

);
```

```js
const items = [{
    "id": 7721,
    "name": "Grilled kebab corn tomato special",
    "purchase_note": "",
    "categories": [{
        "id": 50,
        "name": "All recipes",
        "slug": "0-all-recipes"
      },
      {
        "id": 94,
        "name": "Chef's Special",
        "slug": "chefs-special"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7722,
    "name": "Grilled kebab corn tomato special",
    "purchase_note": "",
    "categories": [{
        "id": 112,
        "name": "All recipes",
        "slug": "0-all-recipes"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "Chef's Special",
        "slug": "chefs-special"
      }
    ]
  }
];


const filtered = items.filter(item =>
  item.categories.filter(c => c.id == 112).length > 0

);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed really appreciate ur help

Comment: filter is not the best method for the inner function, as it will go through all the array without needing to some times

Answer (score 1):

```js
const filtered = data.filter((product) => {
    return product.categories.filter(cat => cat.id === 112)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(your_array.filter(val =>  val.categories.find( item => item.id===112 ))
```

this should give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is **filter** out some elements if their categories have **some** category matching some parameters

so you have

```
menuData.filter(menu => {
  return !menu.categories.some(category => category.id === 112)
});
```